# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required (CloudConnect Salesforce sample ETL SOQL validation error)

Tags: object, salesforce, etl, soql, gooddata

SOQLvalidation threw validation error in CloudConnect Salesforce sample ETL.

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required

Data retrieve target Salesforce organization uses custom domain.
I would like to know what caused above error and how to resolve.

Comment: can you provide more information? Especially the SOQL you are trying to use.

If I understand it correctly this error is thrown during the SOQL Validation in Salesforce Reader component, right?

Thanks!

Comment: also check CloudConnect (Window -> Show view -> Error Log) error log for more information

Comment: We have specified default server host name of login.salesforce.com since this specification were able to establish connection successfully even the organization applied custom domain.
Through Force.com explorer, error throwing sample SOQLs like SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM Account , SELECT Id,Name,StageName,CloseDate,CreatedDate, IsClosed, IsWon, Amount, AccountId FROM Opportunity , SELECT Id, Description, TotalPrice, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem are all executed successfully.

Comment: 'The error means a SOAP request was badly formatted. To use SOAP message, we have to include the message length in the envelope.' was the initial reply from SALESFORCE SUCCESS COMMUNITY ( success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hnkNAAQ ) which I have consulted meanwhile.
My incidental question for this issue is therefore, how server host name at advanced option of Salesforce reader component should be specified if the connection target salesforce organization were applied custom domain.

Comment: The connection target salesforce organization, 'TeamSpirit' is powered by Force.com ERP frontware Salesforce app exchange applicaiton.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003J6KhEAK

http://www.teamspirit.co.jp/spirit/environment/

Comment: Salesforce reader component looks to accept custom domain like https://DOMAIN.my.salesforce.com but not to accept the one like https://teamspirit-2560.cloudforce.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the known issue (bug) in CloudConnect. We are working hard to fix this.

Comment: I would also like to know how much customization is possible for salesforce objects to be requested and retrieved from CloudConnect Salesforce ETL.

Comment: I would further like to know how we can customize SOAP connector to retrieve data from salesforce organization with customized domain and objects.

Comment: Caused by: com.gooddata.clover.plugin.sfdc.SfdcReaderException: Download poll for project:g6jiyog2ay5ntqhl64h85g0b4dbm19l4 returned error:410 status:Gone response body:{"error":{"errorClass":"com.gooddata.gcf.exception.TaskFailException","trace":"","message":"Worker task failed: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required","component":"MSF","errorId":"b8840846-d49d-4f57-966b-49e65e47488c","errorCode":"gdc.gcf.task.fail","parameters":[]}}
 at com.gooddata.clover.plugin.sfdc.SfdcSoqlReader.executeDownloadTask(SfdcSoqlReader.java:125)

Comment: Caused by: com.gooddata.clover.plugin.download.DownloadException: Download poll for project:g6jiyog2ay5ntqhl64h85g0b4dbm19l4 returned error:410 status:Gone response body:{"error":{"errorClass":"com.gooddata.gcf.exception.TaskFailException","trace":"","message":"Worker task failed: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required","component":"MSF","errorId":"b8840846-d49d-4f57-966b-49e65e47488c","errorCode":"gdc.gcf.task.fail","parameters":[]}}
 at com.gooddata.clover.plugin.download.DownloadResultExtractor.executeDownloadAndWaitForFinish(DownloadResultExtractor.java:185

Comment: Caused by: com.gooddata.commons.http.exception.HttpException: Poll returned status 410: Gone
 at com.gooddata.service.http.AbstractPollService.generateHttpExceptionFromPollResult(AbstractPollService.java:198)
 at com.gooddata.service.http.PollService.handleErrorStatus(PollService.java:79)
 at com.gooddata.service.http.PollService.handleErrorStatus(PollService.java:21)
 at com.gooddata.service.http.AbstractPollService.poll(AbstractPollService.java:108)
 at com.gooddata.service.http.PollService.executeAndPoll(PollService.java:66)

Comment: We need a generalized SOAP or REST or Bulk API using connector to retrieve records from powered by Force.com extended web services participating in salesforce app exchange.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000...

They have different SOAP communication behaviour (SOAP request format) in SOQL SOAP request probably because of redirect sign-in authentication communication flow via Salesoforce sales cloud.

Comment: http://www.cloveretl.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/CloverETL-SalesforceBulkAPI.zip

Comment: http://www.cloveretl.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/SalesforceBulkAPI_partnerWSDL.zip

Comment: https://support.gooddata.com/entries/24062663-CloudConnect-Salesforce-Bulk-API-and-REST-API-Connectors

Comment: https://support.gooddata.com/entries/63289428-We-need-a-generalized-SOAP-or-REST-or-Bulk-API-using-connector-to-retrieve-records-from-powered-by-F

Comment: @YuyaKobayashi Hi Could you pls. share your fix?  I meet similar error when using customer url to retrieve sObjects while REST API